# MySQL hyphen in LIKE expression

Tags: php, mysql, escaping

I am working with a legacy PHP framework and am coming across some strange behavior that I can't track down.

I'm running a query that looks something like this

```
select * from table where column like '%word-anotherword%'
```

, which I would like to return records from table where column contains the text "word-anotherword".  (column is a longtext field).

When I run this query in phpMyAdmin, I get the expected results.  But when I run it from inside our framework, I get no results.  I have run it in a separate .php file, using `mysql_link`, `mysql_query` to run the query, and that also behaves as expected.

When I `echo` out the query in the framework directly before it is passed to `mysql_query`, it is formatted just the same as I expect.  I.E. our framework is not escaping it in some unexpected manner.

I am assuming that our framework is overriding some PHP setting somewhere to cause this difference in behavior, but I have had no luck googling for what it might be.  I found [this article](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=2095), which seemed to be a good start, but also didn't quite seem to fit what I'm seeing, since I am getting different behaviors on the same MySQL setup.

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the result of `mysql_client_encoding($link)`

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: Are you sure you do the echo at the right place?

Comment: @Christopher Manning the result of mysql_client_encoding($link) is 'latin1' in both my sample php file that works, and from inside the framework (doesn't work)

Comment: @Jacob Eggers I am using an in house PHP (5.3) framework, and @yi_H I am sure the echo is in the right place, it's directly before the frameworks call to mysql_query, but good question! Been burned by that before ;)

Comment: LIKE is not full text search, that's why question title is wrong and, probably, that article which you found isn't related to your problem. About your problem, open your my.cnf and enable queries log.#Set General Log
log = "C:/genquery.log"

Comment: Not sure if this will help you (probably not), but sometimes it bites people, so: When you `echo` it out, you might want to make sure you're actually seeing the *data* - e.g. if you're `echo`-ing onto a webpage, make sure you're applying `htmlspecialchars()` to the string. Otherwise you might not spot some changes.

Comment: @pinkgothic Gagh! You're totally right, how did I miss that. Much appreciated. And I quickly found the actual issue after seeing how the query was malformed. If you throw this comment in an answer I'll be happy to accept it so this question isn't left open.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @goggin13: Wow. :) Glad that solved it for you. I've posted it as an answer given that it solved it. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a debugging heads-up:

When you `echo` your query out, you might want to make sure you're actually seeing the data - e.g. if you're `echo`-ing onto a webpage, make sure you're applying `htmlspecialchars()` to the string. Otherwise you might not spot some changes.

Comment: *facepalm*  Thank you! Found the error quickly after seeing the actual query before it was going through!

Answer (score 1):

LIKE is not full text search, that's why question title is wrong and, probably, that article which you found isn't related to your problem.

And about your problem, open your my.cnf and enable queries log:

```
[mysqld]

#Set General Log
log = "C:/all_queries.log"
```

Now run your query and look into log.

Comment: I'm having some issues getting the log file set up; I believe `log` is deprecated for MySQL 5.1.6, (or so the server logs tell me), so I have used:  `general_log_file = "queries.log"` and `general_log = 1`.  I can see the queries.log file in the data folder of my MySQL install, and while the server doesn't report any errors finding the log (which it did when I put in bad paths), nothing gets written to it when I run queries.  Do you know what I might be missing?

Comment: Sorry, I have MySQL 5.1. Seems like for MySQL 5.5 you need also log_output = FILE (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_log_output)

Comment: Yup, that works, and thanks for the link!  My issue ended up being something much simpler, as pinkgothic pointed out.  Thanks for the tip for setting up the logs though, I'm sure that will be useful for future debugging! :)